# Succinct data structure for Trie implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, tree, trie

I am trying to implement space efficient Trie data structure as mentioned in the below paper.( completion Trie )

[Space-Efficient Data Structures for Top-k Completion](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/TopKCompletion.pdf)

With above reference I did following steps while making data structure.
1) I created Trie tree ( without compressed ) with 1000 words.
2) Then I traversed tree by level order and created few vectors.

- `vector< bitset<5> > noOfChildren;`
  How many children particular node has. A node can have ( 0 to 26 children) so it can be represented with 5 bits.
- `vector< bitset<5> > charsInBits;`
  The character of a particular node is converted into 5 bits.
- `vector< int> startPosition`
  It is a prefix sum of vector noOfChildren. Which gives the Index of 1st child of a particular node.
- `vector<bitset<1> > leafNode`
  It stores whether that node is leaf node or not. 0 for no leaf and 1 for leaf.

  Now I stored all these vectors data in different files.(.txt)

( Above procedure was one time procedure. )

Now when I run the program, I fetch all the data from (.txt) files into respective vectors.
Then I process all these vectors and successfully traverse through Trie tree.

### Few questions I have

1. Is this a compact Trie representation as I have not stored Trie node address in memory?
2. The files in which I have stored the above vectors data is giving me more size        than my actual 1000 words file size. So I am confused whether I have compressed Trie or not.
3. For more than 1000 words my program gives me "Segmentation fault". It does not even create Trie tree. Why this is happening?

   Note:

   - I have implemented above logic in program and my program is perfectly working for 1000 words.
   - I have not implemented exactly what was said in above research paper.

Comment: Instead of e.g. `vector<bitset<1>>`, why not `vector<bool>`?

Comment: I want to compress Trie  as much as possible. That's why 1 bit was used.

Comment: From [this `std::vector<bool> reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool): "The manner in which std::vector<bool> is made space efficient (as well as whether it is optimized at all) is implementation defined. One potential optimization involves coalescing vector elements such that each element occupies a single bit instead of sizeof(bool) bytes." This one-bit space optimization is rather common.

Comment: Your program is crashing because you made a programming error. We will not be able to tell you which one unless you provide code (a [mcve]) , a stack trace from your debugger, and inputs.

Comment: @Botje  Can you say whether it is compressed trie or not ?

Comment: Looks pretty compact to me. I assume you read that paper and don't have any extra stuff in memory besides that. You are presumably writing all this stuff as binary data into a single file?

Comment: Apart from above vectors , there is nothing in memory. I have stored each vectors data in different files. So I have 4 (.txt) files. Whenever I run program, I load data from these files into memory and traverse through trie.

Comment: Now why these files showing large space because, suppose I have stored char 'a' as 00000 ( i.e. in 5 bits ) but when I stored this in (.txt) file , it is counted as 5 bytes. And that's the reason why it is showing large space for 4 (.txt) files.  Is this correct ?

Comment: That sounds correct. If you want it to take up less space on disk you'll have to create a binary file format. You could perhaps use a serialization library.